# Switching between menus in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I use `kivy` to make a basic menu.

This results in a pretty simple menu. So far so good.

[image]

### The problem

When I click the settings button, I want the app to clear the screen and execute `SettingsMenu` which is supposed to create a button, which should allow me to go back to the main menu. However, pressing the settings button only clears the screen, and doesn't add any new buttons.

How can I go back and forth between these menus? 
Also, what is the right terminology to use here - How do I draw new widgets on my root widget?

The python file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class StartMenu(AnchorLayout):

    def go_to_settings(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        return SettingsMenu()

class SettingsMenu(AnchorLayout):

    def go_to_main_menu(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        return StartMenu()

class SpaceGameApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return StartMenu()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SpaceGameApp().run()
```

And the `.kv` file:

```
#:kivy 1.11.1

<StartMenu>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        size_hint: (0.3,0.5)
        StackLayout:
            spacing:10
            Button:
                size_hint: (1,0.2)
                text: "start"
            Button:
                size_hint: (1,0.2)
                text: "settings"
                on_release: root.go_to_settings()

<SettingsMenu>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x:'center'
        anchor_y:'center'
        size_hint: (0.3, 0.5)
        StackLayout:
            spacing:10
            Button:
                size_hint: (1,0.2)
                text: "back"
                on_release: root.go_to_main_menu()
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to just use a ScreenManager, the point of that is to switch between widget trees. However, it's also trivial to implement from scratch, if you really want to do that then please post a minimal runnable example demonstrating your issues with it.

Comment: @inclement I changed the questions with the full code. `ScreenManager` seems very interesting and definitely something I'm going to use in the future. But at this point I'd like to learn how to get this functionality working (if possible)

Comment: Then your problem is that your code only clears the widgets, it doesn't add anything.

Comment: I thought that by returning an instance of `SettingsMenu` the `.kv` file would create it, just as it did for `StartMenu`. How should I add things to it?

Comment: Using `add_widget`. You've misunderstood why returning a widget works in that specific case, the `build` method is what the app calls to retrieve your root widget but other methods don't have any special behaviour based on return value.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I also misunderstood something more profound. I thought the `.kv` file was the best place to add widgets "in accordance with the separation of concerns". Adding widgets in the python appears in contrast with that. Is it because now widgets are added after user interaction and are therefor considered as part of the logic? What would be best practices in this scenario?

Comment: Kv lets you define static widget trees, it isn't the place to do dynamic widget changes. However, you can separate your concerns by abstracting the widget changes behind a nice api...which is what ScreenManager does. Separation of concerns is a good general principle but it isn't an absolute kv/python thing, it's a general programming concept that you should structure your code around using both kv and python where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. I understand it well enough now to read up on it more